# Database not naturally shrinking log file

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, transaction-log

I have a database that is set to Simple recovery mode. There is 99% free space in the log file and I can manually truncate the log file right down to 500 MB.

The next day, after a daily import process runs, the log file will be back up to ~70GB.

If I check `log_resuse_wait` in `sys.databases` it returns 0 which would indicate nothing is blocking a shrink operation.

Why isn't the log file naturally shrinking? Also, how can I find what SQL queries are causing the log file to grow to such a size?

Comment: Damn it - cannot believe I couldn't find that!

Answer (score 0):

You must check `log_reuse_wait` **during the import process**. Most likely you have a some long running transaction started at the beginning of the import that is pinning the log for the entire import duration. Simple Recovery model log is automatically *truncated*, not shrunk. See [How to Shrink the SQL Server log](http://rusanu.com/2012/07/27/how-to-shrink-the-sql-server-log/).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post: http://blog.sqltechie.com/2011/02/dmvs-instead-of-dbcc-opentran.html

1. Modify the query to suite your needs and store output in a table.
2. Schedule an agent job to run the above (say every 5 min)

Hopefully, when you check the table (after some time), you should be able to see the database size and at what point it started to grow with the relevant message indicating the problem?

I suspect it's the 'size of your transaction / import process' -  *"...the log cannot truncate on checkpoint for any of the changes that are still in open transactions or that have started since that transaction started."* Is there scope to break this import process into smaller chunks?

I hope that helps.